# Top padding for text objects in 1.2.12

Tags: text, padding, space, fabricjs

since V.1.2.12 I see a top paddding for text objects. I used V1.2.9 before and there I did not have that "issue". Is it possible to remove it. I need to use V1.2.12 because of the image issue with loadFromJSON.

See image:

http://imm.io/1g8aV

Comment: I think this might have to do with some lineHeight changes. We'll likely get rid of this soon-ish.